# How to make 1 part of a function "thread wait"?

Tags: c#, multithreading, c#-4.0

I have this function:

```
protected override void WndProc(ref Message message) {
    if (id != null) {
        id.ProcessMessage(message);

        if (id.ScanCode.Length > 4) {
            ...
        }
    }

    base.WndProc(ref message);
}
```

This is doing low-level listening for keyboard input and I suppose has to be multithreaded to do that. It works well, but it's essential that a piece of that function only allow 1 thread at a time to execute:

```
if (id.ScanCode.Length > 4) {
        ...
}
```

I need that entire if-block to only allow 1 thread at a time. As soon as thread #1 finishes, thread #2 can come in and execute. In case it's possible and simple, all other threads could just as well be aborted because by the time a thread gets to this point, the other threads become useless. But if that is difficult or could lead to instability, let's just stick with my original request.

What is the simplest way to achieve this? (Thanks in advance!)

Comment: WndProc only runs on the UI thread.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way of ensuring that only one thread enters a critical section at a time is to use the `lock` statement:

```
private static object lockObject = new object();

protected override void WndProc(ref Message message) {
    if (id != null) {
        id.ProcessMessage(message);

        lock(lockObject) {
            if (id.ScanCode.Length > 4) {
                ...
            }
        }
    }

    base.WndProc(ref message);
}
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz.aspx

Comment: Looks promising and sort of works, but sometimes 2 threads get in there at the same time. Sometimes 1 (good), sometimes 2 (bad). Never more than 2 (could be worse). I'm going to post a new question, so come look in a minute. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Generally the best approach to this is to use the Monitor class, which allows you to lock entry and exit of a block of code:

e.g. an object to monitor:

```
static readonly object _locker = new object();
```

and then your code:

```
lock (_locker) {   
    if (id.ScanCode.Length > 4) {
        ...
    }
}
```

This is a good reference: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/788402/Monitor-and-Lock-in-Csharp

Comment: Ahh... beaten by a minute... ! What paul said :-)

Comment: Elliveny: Thanks for jumping in so quick, but you had a mistake in yours: lock (_object)  instead of lock (_locker)  -- paul had it correct so I awarded it to him. I'm asking a follow-up in a minute if you want to take a stab. New post.